# How to modify third party Api data using Nodejs 'Request' module, before sending it to frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am new to NodeJs, I tried googling but got nothing. I am trying to modify the json data from API link, but it is getting send to frontend angularjs as original json.

```
 app.get('/getCustomers', bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}), function(req, res){  
     var url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php'
      var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        url: url
      }
      request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          inspect(err, 'error posting json');
          return
        }
        var headers = res.headers;  //working
        var statusCode = res.statusCode; 
        console.log(statusCode); //200
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(res.body);//prints original data.
        res.body.extra='jack is cool';

      }).pipe(res);
```

Angularjs Code:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/yo')
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        $scope.getApiResponse = response.data;
        console.log($scope.getApiResponse); //no modifications

    });
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check `APIInterceptors` which will act a firewall or gateway for your request and response,between your server and frontend
Check this `http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want to modify api data on nodejs.